# Insertar en tabla SQL información de JSON

Tags: sql-server

En SQL SERVER me llega un json de la siguiente forma:

```
    {"Data":[{"IdP":4,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":5,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":6,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":7,"Codes": [ {"Code": "ZZ10"},{"Code": "WXW1"},{"Code": "XX02"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":8,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":9,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":10,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":11,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":30,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":31,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":32,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":33,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":34,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":35,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":36,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":37,"Codes": [ {"Code": "ZZ10"},{"Code": "WXW1"},{"Code": "XX02"} ]}] }
```

Necesito insertar la información a una tabla de tal forma que me quede asi:

[image: Tabla SQL SERVER]

He intentado de varias maneras usando OPENJSON y también pasándola a una tabla temporal pero no lo he logrado. Gracias

Comment: Nico, debes ser más cuidadoso al hacer la pregunta. **"En sqlserver me llega"**, eso quiere decir que tu app envía eso a sqlserver? SqlServer recibe eso? O eso lo sacas de SqlServer?

Comment: vale lo tendré en cuenta, la idea es que llega de una app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que complica un poco es que `Codes` es a su vez una lista, pero se puede resolver mediante un `CROSS APPLY`

```
DECLARE @JSON_STR NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @JSON_STR = '{"Data":[{"IdP":4,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":5,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":6,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":7,"Codes": [ {"Code": "ZZ10"},{"Code": "WXW1"},{"Code": "XX02"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":8,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":9,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":10,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":11,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":30,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":31,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":32,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":33,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":34,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":35,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":36,"Codes": [ {"Code": "XX02"},{"Code": "WXW1"} ]}
   ,{"IdP":37,"Codes": [ {"Code": "ZZ10"},{"Code": "WXW1"},{"Code": "XX02"} ]}] }';
   
SELECT A.IdP, B.Code
   FROM OPENJSON(@JSON_STR, N'lax $.Data')
   WITH (   
              IdP       INT           '$.IdP',
              Codes     NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Codes' AS JSON
   ) AS A 
   CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT Code
          FROM OPENJSON(A.Codes)
          WITH (
               Code nvarchar(max)      '$.Code'
          ) 
   ) AS B
```

Comentarios:

- Con `FROM OPENJSON(@JSON_STR, N'lax $.Data')` Leemos a partir de la clave `Data` en modo relajado (`lax`) si falta alguna clave esperado no lanza ningún error y solo completa con `NULL` (Si quieres lo contrario usa `strict`)
- Luego con en`CROSS APPLY` incorporamos una subconsulta pero para leer `Codes`